# How to convert json Request to an array in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony4

I am trying to convert the JSON Request `$request` to an array.

I have output something like this:

```
^ Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request {#45
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#74
    #parameters: array:3 [
      "_route" => "app_movie_create"
      "_controller" => "App\Controller\MovieController::create"
      "_route_params" => []
    ]
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#96
    #parameters: []
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#69
    #parameters: array:1 [
      "title" => "Homecoming"
    ]
  }
```

I have seen some tutorials giving following solutions.

```
 $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('invalid json body: ' . json_last_error_msg());
        }
```

But I am getting null in my case.

I can do like this. `$request->get('title');`

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/@peter.lafferty/converting-a-json-post-in-symfony-13a24c98fc0e) might help

Comment: What would be the expected result? The request you've shared does not contain any body

Comment: You are misunderstanding post data, query data and request content (json formatted), but in case of real json request, you can use: `$request->getPayload()->all()`. See https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-3-mapping-request-data-to-typed-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$request->request->all()` will return you an array of all the parameters that were sent along in the request. `$request->query->all()` will return you an array of all the query parameters that were sent.

`json_decode($request->getContent())` would only work if the person who sends the request is sending you a json string in the raw body. In your case (since you can use `$request->get('title');`), this wasn't happening. The request just contains some parameters and no raw json body.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `$request` is a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` you can:

`$data = $request->toArray();`

to get an array containing the payload.

It does JSON de-serialization under the hood when the request content is properly declared to be JSON via the respective headers.

This is the preferred Symfony way in contrast to `json_decode()` manually.